# How to get option param value from react router without follow sequence (React Router v4)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have to access value to optional param(s) form a react router (React Router v4). Now problem is as we have avoid param(s) sequence.
For example as per following react router code we have to access ***pathPraram2*** without define ***pathPram1*** :

```
<Route path="/to/page/:pathParam1?/:pathParam2?" component={MyPage} />
```

Comment: Are you using react router v4?

Comment: @DanglingCruze yes we are using v4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withRouter` hoc from the `react-router-dom` (or from native router).

This will pass some routing props to your component.

Validate it with `flow` if you want to:

```
type PropType = {
  match: {
    params: {
      pathParam1?: string, // '?' to emphasize its optional 
      pathParam2?: string,
    },
  },
};
```

In your component you can use them by simply checking for their existence.

```
if (this.props.params && this.props.params.pathParam1) {
  // do something
}
```

I hope this helps.

withRouter: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/api/withRouter

Also, extending on @Shubham's answer, I recommend having these optional params with identifiers.

Example:

```
http://example.com/page/identifier-1/param-1/identifier-2/param-2
http://example.com/page/identifier-2/param-2
http://example.com/page
```

This way you can define a route based on page, and in the component you can check based on identifier the param your route contains.

For a route with params like such:

```
{
  articleId: 'abc',
  commentId: 'xyz'
}
```

To create a route mentioned above:

```
<Route path="/page/:key1?/:value1?/:key2?/:value2?" component={MyPage} />
```

Now to access these in component:

```
if (!this.props.match || !this.props.match.params) {
  return;
}

let articleId = null;
let commentId = null;

if (
  this.props.match.params.key1 &&
  this.props.match.params.value1
) {
  if (this.props.match.params.key1 === 'articleId') {
    articleId = this.props.match.params.value1;
  }
  if (this.props.match.params.key1 === 'commentId') {
    commentId = this.props.match.params.value1;
  }
}

if (
  this.props.match.params.key2 &&
  this.props.match.params.value2
) {
  if (this.props.match.params.key2 === 'articleId') {
    articleId = this.props.match.params.value2;
  }
  if (this.props.match.params.key2 === 'commentId') {
    commentId = this.props.match.params.value2;
  }
}
```

then just simple check if `articleId` or `commentId` is null or not.

I think this will lead to a better url formation, though it increases conditions inside the component to get the parameters.

However in Shubham's answer, you will have less conditions and a different url formation. It's upon you to decide which one is preferable for you to use as per your use case.

Hope it helps.

Comment: what is alternative to access http://example.com/action/identifier-1/param-1/identifier-2/param-2  to http://example.com/action/identifier-2/param-2

Comment: Oh I clicked on delete instead of edit by mistake :D

Answer (score 0):

It isn't directly possible for the Router to have an optional path param directly before the other

Consider the case

```
<Route path="/to/page/:pathParam1?/:pathParam2?" component={MyPage} />
```

Now say you wish to have pathParam1 and not pathParam2, so your route path will be

```
/to/page/pathpage1
```

Now consider another case when the pathParam1 is not passed but pathParam2 is, so route path looks like

```
/to/page//pathpage2
```

Now here `pathParam1` will match as empty whereas the `pathParam2` will match to `pathpage2` which will work and you can access it like `this.props.match.pathparam2`

however it not clean in terms of the url as it contains two `//`. As better way would be to introduce a fixed path in between the params

```
<Route path="/to/page(/:pathParam1?)/somepath(/:pathParam2)?" component={MyPage} />
```

Comment: This is exactly my question but what is alternative to avoid prams sequence, like /to/page//pathpage2

Comment: @PrabhuNandanKumar, I did mention it in the answer at the end `<Route path="/to/page(/:pathParam1?)/somepath(/:pathParam2)?" component={MyPage} />`